# I can't get hook_menu() to work

Tags: routes

Hi I am running the code on p247 of "Pro Drupal 7 Development", which includes the code below and then defines a form.  I have enabled the module and cleared the cache but this isn't showing up in my menu system.  What am I doing wrong?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function formexample_menu() {
  $items['formexample'] = array(
    'title' => 'View the sample form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('formexample_nameform'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: have you cleared your cache

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) What do you mean by _"this isn't showing up in my menu system"_? What is your 'menu system' in this case? Do you get a 404 if you visit /formexample?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that MENU_NORMAL_ITEM set two flags for an item to be visible in the menu tree and breadcrumbs.  Sorry if I am mistaken.  Visiting /formexample shows the name of the form but nothing else, so something else is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Karin Try adding something like `'menu_name' => 'main-menu'`, where 'main-menu' is the machine name of the menu you're trying to add it to - that usually does the trick

Answer (score 0):

check 
http:localhost/formexample

Back-end admin panel menu :

```
$items['admin/structure/formexample'] = array(
    'title' => 'View the sample form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('formexample_nameform'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );
```

used this code

Comment: If the menu path is admin/structure/formexample, then visiting http://localhost/formexample doesn't show any form. Changing just the menu path doesn't make the code correct.